# Filter SOLR Search result by Relevance / Score

Tags: search

I am using apachesolr module, i want to filter search result by minimum relevance, i tried following but did not worked, can anyone please help me

In hook_apachesolr_query_alter()

1) Add filter score:[0.5 TO *] with exclude as false
- It display no items

2) Add filter score:[0.5 TO *] with exclude as true
- There is no change in result, it display all items

3) Add parameter q = {!frange l=5}query($qq) and qq = 
Getting 400 error

Comment: is there an answer for this?